# php json_decode

Tags: php, json

Test in some json code, like `[{"a":"1"},{"a":"2"},{"a":"3"},{"b":"2"}]`, I want use json decode, get the data and make a judge, if first `a` nod is `==` `b` nod *or* fisrt `a` nod is `!=` `b` nod. some code here.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$json = json_decode('[{"a":"1"},{"a":"2"},{"a":"3"},{"b":"2"}]',true);
$number=1;
foreach($json as $num){
if($num['a']!=$num['b']){
    if($num['a']){
        echo 'a'.$number.''.$num['a'].'<br />'; 
    }
}else{
    if($num['a']){
        echo 'b'.$number.''.$num['a'].'<br />'; 
    }
}
$number++;
}
?>
```

Now my result is:

```
a11 
a22 
a33
```

And I need get the result:

```
a11
b22
a33
```

Comment: You want to do what exactly? If first a **node** is == b node or fisrt a node is != b node, then what?

Comment: @netcoder, I want make a foreach all the `$num['a']` and make out which `$num['a']` is equal to `$num['b']` such as `a11,b22,a33`

Comment: "Test in some json code", sweet man.

Comment: hey :) , test for further study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you compare non-existing array fields?

there is no $num['b'] field, there are these fields, its array[4] `(index 0..3)`

- a:1
- a:2
- a:3
- b:2

`$num` in first iteration will hold

```
array("a"=>1);
```

so if you wanna compare to `"b":2` you have to use this pattern:

```
$cmpr = array_shift($json);
...
if($num != $cmpr)
```

Array_shift : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: array_pop($json) will output an array. It needs to be array_shift(array_pop($json)) to actually work. **Also**, this will *only* work if you have b set in the final value.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I've repaired my answer. And yes, this code works **only** on given data structure

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to refer to the b variable when b is not currently defined. you must first loop through and find the b variable.
http://codepad.org/0SnrPp6N

```
<?php
$json = json_decode('[{"a":"1"},{"a":"2"},{"a":"3"},{"b":"2"}]',true);
foreach ($json as $var) {
    if (isset($var['b'])) { $b = $var['b']; break; }
}
$i=0;
foreach ($json as $var) {
    if (!isset($var['a']))
        continue;
    if ($var['a']!=$b) 
        echo "a".++$i."$var[a]\n";
    else
        echo "b".++$i."$var[a]\n";
}
```

Comment: not, if the position of B is always known (last element of array)

Comment: @MarekSebera You're correct, but he hasn't specified if it is or not. Because of that, we have to assume it isn't.

Comment: @cj333 this isn't complex at all, either of our answers will work correctly. Your problem is as I described, you're referring to the value of key b when key b isn't set.

Comment: ok, both of u are right, give the mark to the first anwser and give you two +1, thanks all.

Comment: @cj333 is the b key always going to be set in the final array?

Comment: @Korvin Szanto, emm... this is just a test. I have run your code, it is no matter wherever `b` is. And now I am studding `array_pop` on `php.net`.

Comment: @cj333 if the b key is not always set in the last array, array_pop will be no use. If you are not aware of b's position, use my code.

Comment: thanks for remind. now somehow, I know some about `array_pop`, i am not used this function, it is new for me.