# how to decode json array to php array JSON_DECODE

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I have encode a php array with `json_encode` and I store it into db, when I was trying to decode it into a php array I get  null.

this is my php array :

```
'Etablissment' => array(
    'id' => '79',
    'telephone' => '0620000000',
    'nom' => 'RESTo',
    'nbmaxpersonnes' => '20',
    'hoursreservation' => '{"Lundi":{"matin":{"h_debut":"0630 ","h_fin":"0830 "},"midi":{"h_debut":"0730 ","h_fin":"1300 "}},"Mardi":{"matin":{"h_debut":"0700 ","h_fin":"0500 "},"midi":{"h_debut":"1530 ","h_fin":"1400 "}}}'
),
```

I want to decode the `hoursreservation` field so I do `json_decode($etablissement['Etablissment']['hoursreservation'])`, I work with cakephp.
the following solution not working for me:
[php json decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840501/php-json-decode)
and
[json decode in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569008/json-decode-in-php)

Comment: var_dump($etablissement['Etablissment']['hoursreservation']);

Comment: I test you json use json_decode($json, true) works well

Comment: show the code where you are using json_decode

Comment: If you are getting the error or warning while json_decode then please share the error log with us

Comment: I tried `json_decode($array['Etablissment']['hoursreservation']);` (with the array you provided) and it works fine (on my end). Maybe your array isn't a 'array'.

Comment: $etablissement, is that an array of object?

Comment: Think you friends, it works now, I found json array stored id DB with errors format

Comment: Write an answer (and accept one), not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$etablissement = [
'Etablissment' => array(
    'id' => '79',
    'telephone' => '0620000000',
    'nom' => 'RESTo',
    'nbmaxpersonnes' => '20',
    'hoursreservation' => '{"Lundi":{"matin":{"h_debut":"0630 ","h_fin":"0830 "},"midi":{"h_debut":"0730 ","h_fin":"1300 "}},"Mardi":{"matin":{"h_debut":"0700 ","h_fin":"0500 "},"midi":{"h_debut":"1530 ","h_fin":"1400 "}}}'
)];

$d = json_decode($etablissement['Etablissment']['hoursreservation'], true);
$e = json_last_error();

var_dump($d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$etablissement = array('Etablissment' => array(
     'id' => '79',
     'telephone' => '0620000000',
     'nom' => 'RESTo',
     'nbmaxpersonnes' => '20',
     'hoursreservation' => '{"Lundi":{"matin":{"h_debut":"0630 ","h_fin":"0830 "},"midi":{"h_debut":"0730 ","h_fin":"1300 "}},"Mardi":{"matin":{"h_debut":"0700 ","h_fin":"0500 "},"midi":{"h_debut":"1530 ","h_fin":"1400 "}}}'
));

echo json_decode($etablissement['Etablissment']['hoursreservation'],true);
```

You will get array, there is not problem with it.